# Is there a way to play a series of mp4 files without downloading an app?

Tags: files, media-files

If I download several .mp4 files and put them all into a folder, is there a way to play them all, either shuffled or in order?

I just want to avoid having to navigate to the next song every 2-3 minutes.

The device I want to do this with is an HTC OPM9200.

Comment: Um, most video players today can do that? Try MX Player.

Comment: @AndyYan, i cant use an application for reasons.

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b sorry, could you please clarify by "I can't use an application for some reasons"? Just like other OSes, almost everything needs an app to do something, even if it's the stock media player app.

Comment: @AndrewT., I cannot download something to do this.